# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve but I have an error in console. here is my code

```
setInterval(function() {
    removeThis.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeThis.parentNode);
}, 7000);
```

Comment: It's telling you `parentNode` doesn't exist. Without more information about your document, that's all anyone here can tell you. Try logging `removeThis.parentNode` to the console and see what you get.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It's work now